# Can an API in .NET Core 3.1 be made a client of a SignalR hub?

Tags: .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I am developing an application in Xamarin which connects to both a .Net Core 3.1 API and a SignalR server with its corresponding hub. Right now I launch the request to send a notification from the Xamarin application itself, but I would like this request to be sent from the API instead of from the app, and with the existing documentation I have not been able to find a solution.

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide more detail information on what you want to achieve. From what I understood, it could be beneficial for you to learn more about SignalR groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send various notifications to the clients after injecting HubContext in your API. You can inject it for example in your controller class :

```
public class MyController()
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> hub;

    public MyController(IHubContext<MyHub> hub)
    {
        this.hub = hub;
    }

    public Task MyMethodAsync(string message)
    {
        return hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("MessageName", message);
    }

}
```